# Google proxy is a fake crawler? For example: google-proxy-66-249-81-131.google.com

Tags: php, block, web-crawler

****EDIT:***
Solution to this question is below this question because it was not possible to post an answer. People decide to close the question.*

Recently I discover that some variants of a google proxy visits my sites. I doubt these are legal google crawlers because these crawlers are NOT always behind a proxy (like the hostname describes) and identify itself as a browser. The hostname is formatted similar/like google bot but with the string 'proxy' added to it.

My PHP blocking class blocks these crawlers, but is it correct to block these ones? What are they and are these from google or is it fake?

Here some info about one of these crawlers:

```
BlockedIp Notifier Report - IP:66.249.81.131:: has been blocked

Ticket ID : {EVNT_136877_2013040520130402_33147_10348}  
Event type : Access blocked  
Event date : 04/05/2013 - 19:17:47 (server date-time)  
Event counter : First occurring  
Processed url : http://streambutler.net/  
From url : http://www.google.com/search  
Domain : streambutler.net 
Domain IP : 95.170.70.213  
Visitor IP : 66.249.81.131  
Proxy IP : 66.249.81.131  

Critical : Yes  
Action required : No  


Additional information
Problem : Bad Proxy - via 66.249.81.131 
Hostname : google-proxy-66-249-81-131.google.com 
Block : Yes 
Refferer : http://www.google.com/search 
AgentString : Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like G... 
Browser : Chrome 22.0.1229 
Platform : Linux 
Robot : No 
Mobile : No 
Tablet : No 
Console : No 
Crawler : No 
Agent_type : browser 
Agent_name : chrome 
Agent_version : 22.0.1229 
Os_type : linux 
Os_name : linux 
Agent_languagetag : en 
Status : ok 
Request : 66.249.81.131 
Languagecode : us 
Country : United States 
Region : California 
City : Mountain View 
Zipcode : 94043 
Latitude : 37.406 
Longitude : -122.079 
Timezone : -07:00 

Available from  : \'http 
Areacode : 0 
Dmacode : 0 
Continentcode : na 
Currencycode : USD 
Currencysymbol : &#36; 
Currencysymbol_utf8 : $ 
Currencyconverter : 1 
Extended : 1 
Organization : NULL
```

**other variants found**

- google-proxy-66-249-81-131.google.com (identifies itself as Firefox
  6.0 ???)
- google-proxy-66-249-81-148.google.com (tries to access a javascript file)
- google-proxy-66-249-81-131.google.com
- google-proxy-66-249-81-111.google.com (tries to access a javascript
  file)
- google-proxy-66-249-81-164.google.com

**EDIT:**
The next one is a weird one, Firefox 6.0 on Windows 7 and same IP as example above but is not a proxy in the next log? If it is mobile proxy, this is very weird or not?

```
Ticket ID : {EVNT_164838_2013040520130402_33147_10348}  
Event type : Access blocked  
Event date : 04/05/2013 - 19:19:07 (server date-time)  
Event counter : First occurring  
Processed url : http://streambutler.net/  
From url : Unknown or direct link  
Domain : streambutler.net 
Domain IP : 95.170.70.213  
Visitor IP : 66.249.81.131  
Proxy IP : (not present)  

Critical : Yes  
Action required : No  


Additional information
Problem : Blocked Server IP address (analysis) - 66.249.81.131 
Hostname : google-proxy-66-249-81-131.google.com 
Block : Yes 
Refferer : (direct access) 
AgentString : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0 ... 
Browser : Firefox 6.0 
Platform : Windows 7 
Robot : No 
Mobile : No 
Tablet : No 
Console : No 
Crawler : No 
Agent_type : browser 
Agent_name : firefox 
Agent_version : 6.0 
Os_type : windows 
Os_name : windows 7 
Agent_languagetag : en 
Status : ok 
Request : 66.249.81.131 
Languagecode : us 
Country : United States 
Region : California 
City : Mountain View 
Zipcode : 94043 
Latitude : 37.406 
Longitude : -122.079 
Timezone : -07:00 
Available from  : \'http 
Areacode : 0 
Dmacode : 0 
Continentcode : na 
Currencycode : USD 
Currencysymbol : &#36; 
Currencysymbol_utf8 : $ 
Currencyconverter : 1 
Extended : 1 
Organization : NULL
```

---

### **EDIT:** the solution:

**Got it!** These 'crawlers' are not crawlers but are part of the live website preview used in the Google search engine.

I have tried this, to show one of my websites in the preview and yes, there it is, received a blockedIP message.

If you want users to be able to view a preview of your website, you have to accept these 'crawlers'.

Like others said: "the root domain of that URL is google.com and that can't be easily spoofed".

**Conclusion:** You can trust these bot's or crawlers and it is used to show a preview in google search.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't confirmed, but I suspect that these IPs may be associated with Google's Data Compression Proxy for Google Chrome Mobile:

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/data-compression

If this is the case, blocking them will cause your site to display incorrectly for some completely innocent mobile users.

---

It may also be associated with the Google+ crawler used to grab snippets for pages using the Google +1 button:

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=178

Bottom line is, these IPs are used for web requests kicked off by internal Google stuff. They are not public web proxies.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info, didn't know about this. I will take a look and study the info.

Comment: See my edit to the question. Isn't that strange?

Comment: FYI I also received a DOS attack from google-proxy, see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/49521/24148

Comment: A friends webpage was defaced using several google-proxys as springboards.